# Check if today meets a date in tablerow at SQL

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a SQL table with 20 rows. Each row contains a columd 'datum'(date) and a few other data.
To view some information on the website, only when the date of today meets one of the entered dates in the SQL table, I had placed a 'if'.

```
if ($date_now = $feestdag) {
    echo '<i style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">YESS</i>';
}else{
    echo 'Nope</i>';
}
```

The variables used are:

```
 $date_now = date("Y-m-d");
                $resultalert = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT datum FROM feestdagen") or die(mysql_error());
                while($feestdagenalert = mysqli_fetch_array($resultalert)) {
                    $feestdag = $feestdagenalert['datum'];
//removed some data
                }
```

Now, I get everytime the text what I only want to see when the date of today meets ONE of the 20 entries in the table 'feestdagen' at column 'datum'.
Column 'datum' has entries like '2022-01-02', '2022-05-22' et cetera.

Does someone know the solution to make this work? I couldn't find it..
Thanks for help!

Edited: used the solution of khalil and works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT datum FROM feestdagen WHERE datum = CURDATE();`

This will only return that row which has the current date. You don't need to perform a separate check in PHP

Comment: This is the most easy solution I see.. I changed it directly, and tested it (with some changes in the database). It works perfectly. Now only a if($feestdag){ and I'm good to go. Thanks!

Comment: Check the values of the variables by outputting them and see if there actually equal.

Comment: Thanks, I have now changed the codes to check the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM feestdagen
                      WHERE datum = curdate()) AS isfeestdag;
```

You'll get `1`, if today is a holiday, `0` otherwise. Have an index on `datum`, unless `feestdagen` contains only a few rows and this will be blazing fast.